# show 10 results per page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, redux

I want to implement pagination to show the results of car. Per page shows 10 results. I could fetch the result from an API. I could also show the pagination button as per the number of results to show per page. I have no idea on how can i fetch 10 result per page.

**What i have done till now**

```
export function showResultofCar(cityFrom, cityTo, date, paisFrom, paisTo) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'CAR_FETCH_START' });
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return axios.get(`${API_URL}/newoffers/car/{"cityFrom":"${cityFrom}","cityTo":"${cityTo}","date":${date},"paisFrom":"${paisFrom}","paisTo":"${paisTo}"}.json/null/${token}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch({ type: 'CAR_FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data });
        }, 1500);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CAR_FETCH_FAILURE', payload: err });
      });
  };
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
export function getCarResult(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CAR_FETCH_START':
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case 'CAR_FETCH_SUCCESS':
      cars = action.payload;
      return {
              ...state,
              fetched: true,
              fetching: false,
              cars: action.payload,
              currentPage: 0,
              carsLength: action.payload.length
             };
    case 'CAR_FETCH_WITH_FILTER':
      return { ...state, fetched: true, fetching: false, cars: carFilterFromPrice(action.payload) };
    case 'CAR_FETCH_FAILURE':
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**car-result.js**

```
function renderCarList(cars, cityOrigen, cityDestino) {
  if (cars.length > 0) {
    return _.map(cars, (car) => (
      <CarResultList
        key={car.provider_id}
        car={car}
        cityOrigen={cityOrigen}
        cityDestino={cityDestino}
      />
    ));
  }
  return <p> No Car to show </p>;
}

const CarResultList = ({ car, cityOrigen, cityDestino }) =>
<div className="car-result-list">
  <Row className="show-grid" style={{ marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
    <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={8}>
      <h3>{car.car}</h3>
      <p className="sub">{cityOrigen}-{cityDestino}</p>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</div>;

class CarResult extends Component {
  render() {
    const { carResult, origen, destino } = this.props;
    const cityOrigen = origen && origen.label.split(', ')[0];
    const cityDestino = destino && destino.label.split(', ')[0];
    const carResultList = renderCarList(carResult.cars, cityOrigen, cityDestino);
    if (!carResult.fetching) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="car-result-container">
            <Grid fluid>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                  {carResultList}
                  {carResult.carsLength > 10 ?
                    <CarPagination numberOfCar={carResult.carsLength} /> :
                    ''
                  }
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      loading component
    );
  }
```

**pagination.js**

```
export default function Pagination(props) {
  const range = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(props.numberOfCar / 10); i++) {
    range.push(i);
  }
  const numberOfButtonToShow = _.map(range, r =>
    <li className="page-number" key={r}>
      <a href="" className="page-link"> {r + 1} </a>
    </li>
  );
  return (
    <div className="pagination-btns">
      {numberOfButtonToShow}
    </div>
  );
}
```

right now i get all (38) items. How can i make my pagination work?

algorithm for showing data(it does not work for last page, i mean if there is 38 number of results then there will be 4 page, where each page will have 10 content only last page will have 8 content ).

```
[currentPage * 10 , ((currentPage +1)*9)+currentPage] -> [0,9] for page 1 and [10, 19] for page 2 but problem in last page
```

Comment: You need to change the API to return only the first page, I guess your API it's returning all the values, if you don't have control on the API you need to make a filter function to change renderCarList to display only 10 rows

Comment: @damianfabian My API is not designed to return 10 results per page.

Comment: Can you help me on how to do this? Which one will be the better way?

Comment: Change the function renderCarList to accept pageNumber, add a new property like this.state.carPageNumber to save the current page for the pagination and pass this property to your function renderCarList. Into the function return the data base on your page number. i.e. data.slice(0, 9) to return the first 10 rows.

Comment: total of 38?  if you do not expect to ever return more than a couple hundred rows, total, there are plugins such as datatables.net that will take care  of paging,etc for you. just let all the rows come back and set page size

Comment: there will be more than 100. For now its only 38.